# Binary Search Tree can't delete first node

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Whenever I insert the tree data in, and try to delete them, it works for all except the last remaining node. Or even if I insert only one node and try to delete it, it doesn't, it continues displaying the node. I tried debugging the code, but seems clueless. Please help!

```
void Remove(node *Current, int key) {
node *prev = new node;

if(Current == NULL)
    cout << "List is empty.\n";

else {
    while(Current != NULL) {
        if(Current->value == key)
            break;
        else {
            prev = Current;
            if(Current->value >key)
                Current = Current->left;
            else
                Current = Current->right;
        }
    }

    if(Current->left == NULL && Current->right == NULL) {
        if(prev->left == Current)
            prev->left = NULL;
        else
            prev->right = NULL;
        delete(Current);
    }
    else if(Current->left != NULL && Current->right == NULL) {
        if(prev->left == Current)
            prev->left = Current->left;
        else
            prev->right = Current->left;
        delete(Current);
    }
    else if(Current->left == NULL && Current->right != NULL) {
        if(prev->left == Current)
            prev->left = Current->right;
        else
            prev->right = Current->right;
        delete(Current);
    }
    else if(Current->left != NULL && Current->right != NULL) {
        node *temp = Current->right;
        if(temp->left == NULL && temp->right == NULL) {
            Current->value = temp->value;
            delete(temp);
            Current->right = NULL;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////
        else if(Current->right->left != NULL)
        {
            node *left_current = Current->right;
            node *left_current_prev = Current->right->left;
            while(left_current->left != NULL)
            {
                left_current_prev = left_current;
                left_current = left_current->left;
            }
            Current->value = left_current->value;
            delete(left_current);
            left_current_prev->left = NULL;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////

        else
        {
            node *temp;
            temp = Current->right;
            Current->value = temp->value;
            Current->right = temp->right;
            delete(temp);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code has memory leak, why you allocate new memory by `node *prev = new node;`? and why you don't de-allocate it?

Comment: You have a loop that terminates when `Current == NULL` and the next thing you do is dereference `Current`.... since your loop has a `break` I'm assuming you haven't found your crash yet, but it's there if you try to Remove() a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have a guess that you can't delete top node just because you're working correctly just with left and right childs of current node. So you can add additional node that have top node as left child and try to run your method on it. If real top will be deleted - the problem will be solved) But you sould take away memory leaks of course. There must be "delete" for every "new".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I insert only one node and try to delete it, it doesn't, it
>   continues displaying the node

Every tree has a base, a pointer to the first node of the tree.

```
tree base -->  Current node --> left node    ...
                            --> right node   ,,,
```

This base pointer appears to be available to the caller of function Remove,

```
 ... code leading to 
 Remove (tree base->Current, key)
 ... subsequent code
```

but you did not give Remove access to the tree base to modify it.

In other words, Remove() (probably) deletes Current, but tree base still points to where Current was when Remove() returns.

You probably need to review what happens when the key does not match the value in the last node.